# Icinga - Nagios - check_esx3.pl fails while executing

Tags: perl, nagios

I'm trying to add an check_esx3.pl script to my icinga. But trying to execute the script

> ./check_esx3.pl

Gives me the following error:

> Can't locate Nagios/Plugin.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl
>   /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5
>   /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10
>   /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./check_esx3.pl line 31. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at ./check_esx3.pl line 31.

I've been looking around and googling, but I've not been able to find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [`Nagios::Plugin`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Nagios-Plugin/) Perl module.

Answer (score 1):

When you build the Nagios Plugins package from https://www.nagios-plugins.org, one of the configure options is `--enable-perl-modules`. It will build the `Nagios::Plugin:*` modules (since it has several modules included that need them), and install them to your system Perl library directory when you run 'make install' as root.

You can also go directly to the source and install the modules from CPAN, by running the command `cpan Nagios::Plugins` from the command line, also as root. You could possibly run these as the icinga or nagios user, but there's no guarantee they'll get installed into the proper places unless you've done some work beforehand to define PERL5LIB (which is way out of the scope of this answer) and done a bit of hackery in your startup scripts that define a special PERL5LIB for the icinga/nagios process on startup.